# Spring Boot Mapstruct not woking mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

My Dto model

```
public class CoverLetterDto{
  
   private Long user_id;

}
```

My main model

```
public class CoverLetter {
      
       private User user;
    
    }
```

My mapstruct class

```
@Mapping(source="user_id", target = "user")
CoverLetter CoverLetterDtotoEntityCoverLetter(CoverLetterDto dto, User user);
```

Hi everyone  my project using mapstruct but my dto class user_id not mapping user please help me Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
@Mapper
public interface CoverLetterMapper {

    CoverLetterMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CoverLetterMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source="user_id", target = "user.user_id")
    CoverLetter mapCoverLetterDtoToCoverLetter(CoverLetterDto dto);
}
```

Because you're wanting to map `user_id` from `CoverLetterDto` to the `User` class in `CoverLetter`, you have to use *dot notation* to access the `user_id` field in the `user` object.

Please let me know if you have additional questions.